# Changing application menubar in Eclipse RCP

Tags: layout, swt, eclipse-rcp, menubar

I want to change the position of the application menu in an Eclipse RCP application. This is what my UI designer wants it to look like:
[image]
Note that you have the menubar on the left and a tab-bar on the right, thus saving a line of vertical space. I want the menu to still be the application menu, and work with all the other Eclipse extensions for controlling it. I just want it in a different place. Can this be done in Eclipse/SWT?

Comment: Seems unlikely unless you're targeting a single platform?

Comment: Our business need is only for Win64. I'd like too keep the door open for other platforms, but that's a stretch goal. (Not sure it would even make sense on a Mac!) I'm using Eclipse 3.x now, but I'm not against upgrading to 4.x since it will be full released before my product ships.

Answer (score 1):

Not by default, certainly not in Eclipse 3.x or even Eclipse 4.2 using the Workbench.  RCP applications fill in the main menu bar using their subclass of `org.eclipse.ui.application.ActionBarAdvisor`, filling in `org.eclipse.jface.action.MenuManager`s.  All of the default extensions in 3.x are also based on interacting with `MenuManager`s.  The SWT `Menu` used in the menu bar doesn't allow that kind of overlay, AFAIK.

In Eclipse 4 the menus are described in a model, and then a variety of renderers (defaults provided by `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.WorkbenchRendererFactory`) are responsible for creating the SWT widgets.  In theory it's possible to replace some or most of those renderers (in effect implementing your own menu system using SWT composites or buttons or canveses) but that sounds like a lot of work.

Comment: It might not be so bad if I used Swing menus as the representation. You can place a Swing menu anywhere you want. I just didn't want to do that since I'd lose all the support Eclipse has for managing your menu. But it sounds like I can still use that by writing a renderer in Eclipse 4. Thanks.